# asp mvc controller creation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

i want dynamically create ascx files, to partial render them.
but as i know, ot show them , i at least need dummy method:

```
public ActionResult test()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

how can i create this method for each new ascx file?

upd: i need factory?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you create dynamic ascx files?

If you want to create all the layout in the controller you should be able to return it directly.

But then, why would you do that?
This way it will be really hard to do unit testing and refactoring and reuse.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to create your .ascx controls ahead of time.  If you are doing this, I would recommend that you register a new view engine to provide a new `PartialView` location.

```
public class MyViewEngine : WebFormsViewEngine
{
  public MyViewEngine()
  {
    PartialViewLocationFormats = new[]
    {
      "~/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx",
      "~/Views/GeneratedControls/{0}.ascx",
      "~/Views/Shared/{0}.ascx"
    };
  }
}
```

This allows you to write your dynamic views to the `/Views/GeneratedControls/` folder. If you need to use a specifically named control (i.e. the control you generate has a random name) then you simply need to adjust your call to `PartialView`:

```
public ActionResult test()
{
  return PartialView("name-of-control");
}
```

Otherwise MVC will use the name of the `Action` as the name of the control to use.